# PHP exporting data to CSV in multiple sheets

Tags: php, phpexcel, fputcsv

Each day I run a cron where it finds data that has not been pulled/exported yet (via a column "exported" that contains a boolean) and this works fine. However, now I'd like to do a loop for each of the results and stick them in to the exported CSV in their own sheets grouped by the datetime.

My new CSV should look like:

```
Sheet 1 (12-04-2015)   Sheet 2 (13-04-2015)   Sheet 3 (14-04-2015)
```

And within those sheets display the grouped data that has the datetime column set for that day.

My current CSV export code:

```
    $file = date('YmdHis');

    $fp = fopen('/var/www/exports/'.$file.'.csv', 'w');

    $count = 0;

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
        $data[] = array($row['email'],$row['first_name'], $row['last_name'], $row['datetime']);

        if( strlen($cleared)>0 ) $cleared .= ",".$row['id'];
        else $cleared = $row['id'];

        $count++;

    }

    foreach ($data as $d) {
        fputcsv($fp, $d);
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

Can I do this using fputcsv, and how would I do so, or would I have to use `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();` instead (which I know how to do)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSV does not support sheets, so you would need to go with something a bit more powerful, like `PHPExcel`. New sheets can be created using `$php_excel->createSheet();` method. You will get a `PHPExcel_Worksheet` instance that you can populate.

Comment: Thanks @Ilija just as I suspected.